# Netty remoteAddress from channel is null

Tags: java, netty

The following code is from a piece from a extended class of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("channel inactive, reconnect to the server.");
    long sleepTimeMs = 1000;

    final EventLoop eventLoop = ctx.channel().eventLoop();
    SocketAddress socketAddress1 = ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
    eventLoop.schedule(() -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("Reconnecting ...");
            tcpClient.connect(ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }, sleepTimeMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    ctx.fireChannelInactive();
}
```

Without having

```
SocketAddress socketAddress1 = ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
```

the following line would throw a `NullPointerException`:

```
tcpClient.connect(ctx.channel().remoteAddress())
```

as the `ctx.channel().remoteAddress()` param is `null` (I tested it multiple times with and without `socketAddress1` assignment).

Any explanation of this?

Comment: Would you be able to include the stack trace for the error?

Comment: @tmarwen Hi, error stack itself is very boring, a plain NPE. But you may find more in the following links: I left an `issue` at https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/12405. And runnable code is at `https://github.com/Jovons/alive-netty`

Comment: Great, you should then have better support from the netty team out there.